# Experiences with intro video in remote companies?

Tags: human-resources

Reemote onboarding can be difficult and impersonal, especially during the first few hours or days. Do you create an introduction video with the other team members to mitigate this? Did it work? What was your experience?

Answer (score 4):

Setting aside that the fact that probably 99% of all internal company videos are drek, I think that even if you've got a budding Steven Speilberg in your ranks or have something professionally produced it's still a poor way to achieving your goals here.

Remote on-boarding being impersonal is not going to be reduced by watching pre-recorded footage - you're going to lose all the interactivity that forming connections between people requires. Even if your new hire does a superhuman job of absorbing the detail about the team and *somehow* gets a sense of knowing them you're neglecting the fact that introductions and on-boarding is a two-way process. It's as much about getting your existing employees to know the new hire as it is the other way around.

This is why video-meeting software exists - Zoom, Teams, Google Meet, Discord, Skype, there's plenty to choose from. While it's not as effective as meeting in person it's infinitely more so than an awkward "introduction video". Depending on the size of the team there's an argument that a single video meeting could be chaotic and overwhelming - but there's nothing to say you can't have multiple, either in manageable groups or even individually.

Comment: Maybe onboarding is the wrong term to use. "Introduction" might have been better? What I meant is that not everybody will be available on the first few days to have a video call (due to holidays, time zones, part time working). Do you think it would still be wrong to have these colleagues record a short video?

Comment: @FrankGroeneveld I don't think the availability concerns you mention would be any different from the "normal" spread out introductions you'd do in an in-person scenario. "Wrong" is probably too strong a word, I just don't see any benefit to doing so.